# Is there a way to scale circular faces individually?

Tags: modeling

I've tried setting the pivot point to "individual origins" and changing the orientation of scale tool to normal but neither worked. It seems that those methods only work when the face is actually separated. I don't want the faces go towards the center so I manually scaled edges so that it works kinda like the "inset" feature, but is there a more effieicnt way to do this? I believe this feature was called Extrude > offset in Maya so I'm hoping for something like that.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't clear. Inset creates additional faces, but I want the selected faces itself get thinner.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible, so maybe inset then dissolve the edges you don't want?

Comment: Scale them along **local** axis.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Scale radial edges around individual origins.**

*Rather than a face selection, suggest in this case using edges.  Scaling  the radial edges about their individual origins will have the desired effect*

[image]

- Select a radial edge to be scaled.
- Select edge ring to get all radials of inner ring
- With pivot point set to individual origin scale.

Comment: ... and.. Indiana Jones re-holsters his revolver.